# Merging two classes with one different field into one in Java

Tags: java

Having two classes with all fields equal except one.

> Class A: String S1; String S2;
>
> Class B: String S1; String S3;

Desired result:

> Class C: String S1; List{S2, S3};

Is there any compact solution to merge into another class merging different field to a collection? String S1 - primary key.

Comment: do you want to achieve it at compile time or run-time?

Comment: what do you want to do with your `C` class, do you want to access the list as a one, or just one of the both `S2` **or** `S3`

Comment: you want to merge Classes at runtime? Or objects of class A and B?

Comment: Java is fairly rigid when it comes to classes, maybe you'll better use flexible data structures than classes. Like a map of lists in this case

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create an `Object` of type `C` during Compile time. You *have* to introduce another class. Something like the following:

```
public class C {

     final String S1;
     final String List<String> S2AndS3;

     public C(A a, B b){
          if(!a.S1.equals(b.S1)){
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not the same primary key");
          }
          S1 = a.S1;
          S2AndS3 = Arrays.asList(a.S2, b.S3);
     }
}
```

which then can be easily called like this:

```
A a = ...;
B b = ...;
C c = new C(a,b);
```

Which "merges" the both objects into one, as desired.